# How to write a program thats asks for a letter and number then prints out the letter that many times in python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to type a letter then a number after that it prints out the letter as many times as the number, here is my code.

```
letter = input('Please enter a letter: ')
number = input('Please enter a number: ')
for i in range(number, letter):
    print(i)
```

and this is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lajdt/Desktop/GCSE/Task 8/Task 8b.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in range(number, letter):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
letter = input('Please enter a letter: ') 
number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
print(letter*number)
```